# mySql Max function ot returning exact result

Tags: mysql

I don't know why i am not getting the exact result

```
SELECT MAX(MID(order_id,3,20)) As Id FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE `domain_id`=2 
+------------+
|   id       |
+------------+
|  10121452  |
+------------+
```

Even i tried the same function without MID function

```
SELECT MAX(order_id) As Id FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE `domain_id`=2 
+------------+
|   id       |
+------------+
| Hy10121452 |
+------------+
```

any my database have highest order

```
+--------+------------+
| id     |  order_id  |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | Hy10121452 |
| 2      | Hy10121453 |
| 3      | Hy10121454 |
| 4      | Hy10121455 |
| 5      | Hy10121456 |
| 6      | Hy10121457 |
| 7      | Hy10121458 |
| 8      | Hy10121459 |
| 9      | Hy10121460 |
+--------+------------+
```

i have to increment in the highest number to generate new order No.
Is i am doing something wrong?

Comment: where does `domain_id` come from?

Comment: html select drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your database -> table-> column the data does not contain the same values like this a**bc1 abc2 abc3 xxx1** if you differnt series then the result always wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change `MAX(MID(order_id,3,20))` to `MAX(MID(order_id,3,))`

Syntax:from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp)

```
 SELECT MID(column_name,start[,length]) AS some_name FROM table_name;
```

where

```
column_name   Required. The field to extract characters from
start         Required. Specifies the starting position (starts at 1)
length        Optional. The number of characters to return. If omitted, the MID() function returns the rest of the text
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) As Id FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE `domain_id`=2

Comment: @HamzaYounas The problem may be because of some special character in your query

Comment: SELECT MAX(MID(order_id,3,)) As Id FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE `domain_id`= 2

Comment: Maybe leaving the last parameter empty is the problem.. Try like this `MAX(MID(order_id,3,8))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the highest id  then you can use `order by DESC` and `limit`

```
SELECT order_id As Id FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE `domain_id`=2 ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: same problem might b some thing wrong i have to figure it out

Comment: which table does `domain_id` belong? that might be the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved i just have to rectify Order_id column it contains the duplicate entries. duplicate entries removed and problem solved like a charm.